# I have no images in an activated wp theme

Tags: images, themes, activation

With this line everything works fine - (as a **Non-Wordpress** index.php):

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

When I activate the file as a wp theme and replace above line with:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

everything is ok, except - there are no images.

For example - a div with an image:

```
<div id="about">
<img id="thinker01" src="images/thinker01.png" width="120" height="163" />
</div>
```

**images** folder is inside theme's folder.

Comment: Where are these images stored? According to your source, your "images" folder must be located in the same place as index.php

Comment: @OneTrickPony, yes, it is.

Comment: Just as a note: your *stylesheet link* really has no bearing on your problem; rather, the issue is with *HTML image SRCs*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> images folder is inside theme's folder.

But relative URLs do not work that way. They are relative to the URL not to the filesystem path. Your problem is here:

`<img id="thinker01" src="images/thinker01.png" width="120" height="163" />`

If you look at the request (via HttpFox or other means) you will see that the browser is looking for the image at `http://your-site.com/images/thinker01.png` and not at `http://your-site.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/images/thinker01.png` Don't use relative URLs like that. Give it a complete path as you did with your stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

you should declare the full url to your theme , eq:

```
<img id="thinker01" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/thinker01.png" width="120" height="163" />
```

Comment: what I usuualy do is use 'replace' on my ide:<br /> fint: src="images/   replace to: src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/

Comment: +1, though you should use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `bloginfo( 'template_url' )`.